# use of lambda and streams on nested object

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, mapping, java-stream

I want to use lambda and streams on a complex nested object and want to compare the dates. can someone help how can I do it using lambda expression

From below object I want to filter out all asset item ids with ownership start date < employee joining date and want to put all  those ids to an Array List

The code I have so far gives me all the asset item ids , I dont know how to use filter to compare  item.ownership.startDate with emp.joiningDate

```
{
  "transactionDate": "",
  "employees": [
    {
      "joiningDate": "2018-06-12T07:13:48.504Z",
      "assets": [
        {
          "assetItem": [
            {
              "id": "1",
              "ownership": {
                "startDate": "2017-06-12T07:13:48.506Z",
                "endDate": "2017-06-12T07:13:48.506Z"
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "assetItem": [
            {
              "id": "2",
              "ownership": {
                "startDate": "2018-06-12T07:13:48.506Z",
                "endDate": "2018-06-12T07:13:48.506Z"
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "assetItem": [
            {
              "id": "3",
              "ownership": {
                "startDate": "2017-06-12T07:13:48.506Z",
                "endDate": "2017-06-12T07:13:48.506Z"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Below is the code I have which I want to modify

```
  List<String> assetList = object.getEmployees().stream().
            flatMap(emp -> emp.getAssets().stream()).
            flatMap(asset -> asset.getAssetItem().stream()).
            map(item -> item.getId()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The expectation is to have only asset item id 2 in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mixed approach with a `for` loop iteration of the collection of `Employee`s and streaming over the assets per employee and then `filter`ing and `map`ping based on the condition and to item ids respectively.

```
List<String> assetItemIds = new ArrayList<>();
for (Employee employee : employees) {
    assetItemIds.addAll(employee.getAssets().stream()
            .flatMap(asset -> asset.getAssetItem().stream())
            .filter(assetItem -> assetItem.getOwnerShip().getStartDate() >= employee.getJoiningDate())
            .map(AssetItem::getId)
            .collect(Collectors.toList()));
}
```

Though a little complex structure of converting this into a single stream operation would be to create an entry of `Employee` and the `AssetItem` stream with the filter operation being the trick and then mapping the values accordingly. This could be achieved as follows:

```
List<String> assetItemIds = employees.stream()
        .map(emp -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(emp,
                emp.getAssets().stream()
                        .flatMap(asset -> asset.getAssetItem().stream())
                        .filter(assetItem -> assetItem.getOwnerShip().getStartDate() >= emp.getJoiningDate())))
        .flatMap(e -> e.getValue().map(AssetItem::getId))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Naman , let me try this. I will get back with the results !

Comment: @R_Jain I have question. what is this called"AssetItem::getId"inside map.
and also if I have another object inside getId say getRealId so how will I write it?
AssetItem::getId::getRealId??